# Running Variance Calculation

Tags: variance

I was looking for a one-pass way to calculate variance over a sliding window. I found an efficient way using Power Sum Averages.However, I am looking for a solution that doesn't require me to store previous data points. Although, the above mechanism requires just 1 historic value (series[bar-period]) to calculate the current variance. In a sliding window, in effect it requires all the values for future calculations.

Is there a workaround to this problem?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! Unfortunately this question isn't a great fit for the site as it stands. We typically ask for a higher standard, demonstrating research effort and understanding. Which language are you writing this in? Perhaps the code of your attempts would help us? Reading the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) is always useful when you try a new site :-)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to efficiently calculate a moving Standard Deviation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14635735/how-to-efficiently-calculate-a-moving-standard-deviation)

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options:

1. Use an incremental algorithm for mean/variance and add the element you are dropping out of the window with a weight of -1. But you still need to store them all so you know what to drop. You may be asking for the impossible.
2. You might try the Python [momentum](https://github.com/microprediction/timemachines) package, or translate from the same, if you want a really small state. I am the author.